# How to send a simple email using PHP code

Tags: php

I would like to send an email to my gmail account using some simple PHP code. The code below works in terms of execution, however the problem is even thought is says "Message Sent" I am not receiving my email in my gmail account. Please advice

```
ini_set('SMTP',"smtp.gmail.com");
    $to ="example@gmail.com"; // this will be replaced with my actual email
    $from ="example@gmail.com"; // this will be replaced with senders email

    $message = $_GET['Message'];
    $subject = "This is a test";

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$from))
    {
        echo "Message Sent";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "Message Not Sent";
    }
```

Comment: To successfully connect to email accounts like GMAIL you have to sign in with a userid/password before they will play with you. Thats not possible using vanilla PHP. Have a look at [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) as a great library that gets you over this issue

Answer (score 1):

Steps to send a simple email

- Go to google
- Search for "PHP Mail"
- Click the first result
- Read, read, keep reading, wait, read it over, read on
- Enjoy!

But seriously:

(Examples are taken from PHP.net)

#### Example 1

Sending a simple email

Using `mail()` to send a simple email:

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

#### Example 2

Sending mail with extra headers.

The addition of basic headers, telling the MUA the From and Reply-To addresses:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use his line of code:

```
$to ="example@gmail.com"; // this will be replaced with my actual email
$from ="example@gmail.com"; // this will be replaced with senders email

$headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";
//$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = $_GET['Message'];
$subject = "This is a test";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```